# Не переведена плашка про конкурс

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, конкурс

См., например,
[тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1090655/180092).

> **The bounty expires через 7 дней.**  Answers that other users post
> to this question are eligible for a +50 reputation bounty.  Ainar-G
> wants to **draw more attention** to this question:

Comment: Появился перевод)

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Спасибо, но часть про «Answers that other users post» всё ещё не переведена.

Comment: Разве? У меня там "За ответ на этот вопрос может быть присуждена награда в размере +50 баллов репутации".

Comment: Что-то с кешами?  У меня [вот](https://send.firefox.com/download/ec8d1b564ac32b0a/#mtgx2UEW7fnBwORoxmb1ew).

Comment: Интересно, а если с помощью ctrl+f5 обновить?

Comment: Только так и обновлял.

Comment: Подозреваю, что разница в том, что вы автор вопроса. Вижу там ещё несколько не переведённых строк. Сейчас добавлю переводы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14259

Добавил перевод:

> $bountyStarterLink$ хочет **привлечь больше внимания** к этому вопросу:

С обновлением движка появится (завтра вечером, вероятно).